# Renaming Web.config to run transforms breaks nuget package installation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, msbuild, nuget

I have a simple scenario where I have my Web.config and then a Web.Release.config that I want to use to transform the Web.config when I deploy to production. Transforms only automatically run if you publish within VS, and I am not using VS for deployment, I'm using outside source control along with cruise control to build and deploy.

I've seen several solutions to this problem:

1) use a base web.config file (Web.base.config) so that the Web.config file can be overwritten during the build process by modifying the project file.
2) install an extension that handles this
3) within cruise control import the targets and essentially do the same thing as #1 manually running the transform, but this still requires a base config file separate from the destination web.config

The issue with all of these is that I have to rename my web.config (eg. to Web.base.config) or I have to move the web config to a different directory so that once the transform occurs it doesn't overwrite my base (original) web.config.

If I do this, then when I install/update any nuget packages that modify the web.config, it will add the changes to Web.config which will be overwritten everytime the transform occurs, when the changes really need to be applied to the base web config.

I've searched everywhere and noone has mentioned this as an issue. Am I missing something? I'm hoping someone can offer a solution that doesn't require the original Web.config filename/location to change.

Answer (score 1):

It's because transformation task itself locks web.config.

I believe the simplest solution would be to use copy task and copy your config to web.config.copy before transformation. Then transform your web.config.copy to web.config.transformed and then just copy it back into web.config.

Copy task can overwrite readonly so you shouldn't have any problems with source-controlled files

Comment: What's the point of web.config.transformed in this scenario? Can't I just transform web.config.copy to web.config?

Comment: Also, what does this mean for source control? If I build using cruise control, it takes down latest source, copies the web.config to web.copy.config, then transforms the copy to web.config. That's great. Now, if I run the build again without making any changes to source, won't it copy the already transformed web.config to start the process all over again? So basically it will be transforming the web.config that was already transformed the first time around.

Comment: 1. You can try. We are using TFS and when Build Agent gets latest source code - all files in a workspace are read-only. So we are using intermediate file .transformed to capture task output and then we are using copy task with OverwriteReadOnlyFiles=true to avoid any read-only issues.

Comment: 2. I would prefer to have a clean copy from repository every time, no matter is that new build or repeated one. I believe that building same source code (not a "fresh copy" from vcs) multiple times is a bad practice that causes more problems than solves. But the answer to your question, in general, is "I think so, it'll use the file you have on disc". In your particular case - I don't know how your CC was set up, maybe there is a way to fetch fresh copy before build and CC is set up to do so :).