# Intercept .nuget Transformation Install/Uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, nuget

Similar Question: [Renaming Web.config to run transforms breaks nuget package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750213)

I am trying to get my build transformations of config files to work together with nuget. I have a Web.Base.Config, Web.Debug.Config, etc.

If its not possible to change the target of the nuget to target the Web.Base.Config instead of Web.Config, then I wanted to cause the Web.Base.Config to get copied to Web.Config before the nuget transform and copy back from the Web.config to the Web.Base.config after the transform.

Is there a way I can create a BeforeTarget AfterTarget task to do this? I'm not sure of what the targets in nuget would be.

Or is there another solution to being able to doing build transformations on the development machine?

Edit:

I found that I can install Nuget.Core into my project and there is a event called PackageReferenceAdding in the ProjectManager class, if I could figure out how to hook into this somehow from the UI interface to do a `<Copy SourceFiles="Web.Base.config" DestinationFiles="Web.config" />` or something of the like.

Edit 2:
I found Nuget.VisualStudio (I'm not sure if this is suppose to be called by a project inside nuget or a solution installing a nuget package, there isn't much information that I could find)
And think that something like the code below should work if it were triggered at the right time:

```
    private void CopyTask()
    {
        var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        var installerServices = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerEvents>();
        installerServices.PackageInstalling += metadata => {
            //Copy Web.Base.Config to Web.Config
        };
        installerServices.PackageInstalled += metadata =>
        {
            //Copy Web.Config to Web.Base.Config
        };
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell us why do you want the nuget target the Web.Base.Config instead of Web.config? The transformation action is a standalone action, which I don't find any before/after event to do other operations.

Comment: The Web.config is changed by the local build process, i want a source config that does not get modified by the transformation process, as well as a debug config that is separate. I could manually copy the web.base.config into the web.config everytime before i use nuget, but I was hoping to automate it.

Comment: Could you share the local build process since no matter I build in debug mode nor in release mode, the Web.config file is not changed in my side? And if the local build process need to changed the Web.config, which should be needed by your project requirement, why do you still want to change it back?

Comment: @Wendy I use
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
see: https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216

Answer (score 0):

The nuget target to Web.config is generated when project created and nuget installed. It is not target on build process. But the Transform action is operated on build process and it will transform entire file, not part of the file. So we could not change the target of the nuget to the Web.Base.Config.

In addition, we often manage nuget packages install/uninstall in packages.config file. In Web.config file, it just list the assemblies that used in current project. They are two different actions.